# Issue with writing a variable value to a file

Tags: python-2.7

I'm quite new to python and please excuse me if the question is stupid. I'm basically trying to write data to a file , here is the snippet

```
for i in range(1,10):
    f.write(" %d] %s This is a log entry" % (ctime(),i) + "\n")
    n += 1
```

and I get an error

```
%d format: a number is required, not str
```

My intention is to get an output which says as follows

```
1] Wed Jul  9 20:50:35 2014 :: This is a log entry
  ..
  ..
 10] Wed Jul  9 20:50:35 2014 :: This is a log entry
```

Advice would be highly appreciated

THanks

Answer (score 4):

Looks like your ctime() and i are flipped around. It should be

```
f.write(" %d] %s This is a log entry" % (i, ctime()) + "\n")
```

The way you had it had the ctime() being inserted into the %d and the i inserted into the %s, which is the opposite of what you wanted.